# reading an integer from console in java

Tags: java, io

How to read an integer input in java ..
I tried buffered reader and scanner..but it doesn't output anything..I am using eclipse indigo..will it affect the output..

sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int a;
    try {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);     
      a = sc.nextInt();
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
      System.err.println("Not a valid number: " + ex);
      return;
    }
    System.out.println("I read this number: " + a);

}
```

Comment: Nothing's wrong with the code, it works. Try again.

Comment: Your IDE won't affect the output. What happens when you try to run it?

Comment: nothing is being returned..just a blank screen ..should I import anything for tis

Comment: A `Scanner` doesn't throw a `NumberFormatException` on a failing `nextInt()`, but an `InputMismatchException`, `NoSuchElementException` (or `IllegalStateException` if the `Scanner` is closed).

Comment: Do you see console output when you run just this: public static void main(String[] args) { System.out.println("hello world!"); } ?

Comment: @balaji You should type the number and press enter. You will see output.

Comment: yes..i can see the hello world..

Comment: Blank screen appears, then you have to enter an int, then it shows something.

Comment: @achintya:yep thanks,,it works when i type in and enter//..So silly mistake

Comment: Update your code to add prompt to the user: "Please enter a number and press <enter>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what are you trying to do: You are seeing nothing because Eclipse prompt you to enter the integer number, so when you see the cursor in your Eclipse's console, just enter a number and you'll see the output. the new Scanner(System.in) will actually wait for you to enter an int